# Считывание данных

Tags: c++

Как обработать строку что-бы получился массив чисел?

input: `5 8 17 3 68`

output: `[5,8,17,3,68]`

Comment: Есть ли аналог split питона?

Comment: http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/how-to-split-a-string-in-c.html

Comment: А можно тогда как-нибудь попроще сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::stringstream ss(str);
int data;
str::vector<int> parsed;

while (ss >> data)
{
    parsed.push_back(data);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "Let me split this into words";

istringstream iss(text);
vector<string> results(istream_iterator<string>{iss}, istream_iterator<string>());
```

[Отсюда](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/04/21/how-to-split-a-string-in-c/)

Comment: Можно еще немного ужать: `vector<string> results(istream_iterator<string>(iss), {});`.